# Does domain name change on salesforce new release

Tags: lightning, mydomain, custom-domain

Does domain name change on salesforce new release. For example, currently we have following domain name: test--PCSandbox.**cs12.my.salesforce.com**.
In the new Salesforce release, will the domain name get updated?
When does the domain name gets updated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Components of the URL:

```
test--PCSandbox.cs12.my.salesforce.com
^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
||||  ||||||||| |||| |||||||||||||||||
Domain Name ||| |||| Custom Domain URL
      ||||||||| ||||
      Sandbox Name |
                ||||
                Pod Identifier
```

- The Domain Name itself will not change at any time, unless you take pains to [rename it yourself](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_rename.htm&type=5).
- The Sandbox Name cannot be changed. If you want a different one you will have to create a new sandbox.
- The Pod Identifier will not change at any scheduled interval. If your pod is changed, you will be notified ahead of time (at least for production orgs). For a sandbox it is subject to change during refresh.
- The Custom Domain URL will not likely change any time soon.

Note that you can generate your domain specific URL without any need for hard-coding, so there is never any need to do so. Simply use the [`URL.getOrgDomainUrl()`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm) method.

> Returns the canonical URL for your org. For example, `https://yourDomain.my.salesforce.com` or, for orgs without My Domain enabled, `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com`.

Comment: The pod identifier is being removed in Spring '19, though.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [Critical Update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_security_other_changes.htm#rn_security_sandbox_domain_update) that addresses this. Around March, 2019, the domain name will no longer include the host name. You can test this now in your org by enabling the Critical Update in the Setup menu. Aside from that, the URL did not historically change with each new release. It could, however, change between Sandbox Refresh requests.